# I keep getting this error while i try to use npm start on my react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image: picture]

The error keeps coming up every time i use npm start. i am a complete beginner

Comment: NPM is looking for a file called `package.json` in the current directory. Either you are in the wrong directory, or you havent generated the `package.json` file, you can do that by running [`npm init -y`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/init)

Comment: Please include the code and error message as text instead of as an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traverse to my-app folder which is inside your My App folder and then run `npm start`

Answer (score 0):

Congrats on your first react app!

The `npm start` command looks in your package.json file for a script. It will look something like this:

```
'scripts': {
     'start': 'node app.js'
}
```

Your error is saying that your terminal can't find the package.json file at all. Make sure your terminal is in the same directory as your package.json file. If you type the `ls` command in your terminal it should show your package.json file. If you don't see it, you can use `cd ..` to move up a directory, or `cd {folderName}` to move down a directory. You want to be in the my-app directory. The `pwd` command will print the directory you're currently in.

Answer (score 0):

You have created a `my app` folder inside another `my app` folder, and your working directory is the first folder which doesn't have a package.json file. You must change your terminal directory to inner `my app` folder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run your command from directory which contains package.json. Probably you will also need to use command `nmp run start` instead. By the way folders with spaces in names may cause some problems later. I would recommend to remove spaces.